# Gradle equivalent for mavens maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

I'm moving from Maven to Gradle, 
In my maven code i used the "maven-dependency-plugin" 
and i could not find an easy translation for the following:
so my question is how can i get my dependencies into a specific structure?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.group1</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
                        <version>1</version>
                        <type>swf</type>
                        <outputDirectory>/flex/output1</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>artifact1.swf</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.group2</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
                        <version>2</version>
                        <type>swf</type>
                        <outputDirectory>/flex/output2</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>artifact2.swf</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>com.group3</groupId>
                        <artifactId>artifact3</artifactId>
                        <version>3</version>
                        <type>swf</type>
                        <outputDirectory>/flex/output3</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>artifact3.swf</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636702/gradle-equivalent-of-maven-dependency-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

so finding no equivalent in Gradle what i ended up doing is holding a map of artifact id to the new name (outputDirectory + destFileName) and after resolving the dependencies into a new special configuration which i called "Flex" and then renaming every dependencies from "flex" using the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for Maven-like dependency management features in Gradle, check out the [Dependency Management Plugin](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin). It provides familiar `dependencyManagement` blocks and BOM support.

Note that you don't need to use Spring in your project to use the plugin.