# equivalent gradle for outputDirectory tag from maven

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, dependency-management

I have maven dependency like this:

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>de.darmstadt.tu.crossing</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaCryptographicArchitecture</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <classifier>ruleset</classifier>
    <type>zip</type>
    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
    <includes>**</includes>
</artifactItem>
```

I want same for gradle build. I am currently using this:

```
compile group: 'de.darmstadt.tu.crossing', name: 'JavaCryptographicArchitecture', version: '1.5+',ext: 'zip',classifier: 'ruleset', changing: true
```

I need equivalent outputDirectory, includes tag in gradle. It's really important which I can't avoid. Experts, please give your suggestions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle equivalent of maven-dependency-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636702/gradle-equivalent-of-maven-dependency-plugin)

Comment: Why do you need maven-dependency-plugin in your build?

Comment: The problem is not solved yet. I don't have configuration tag in my maven.